# Example query to load OpenPhacts data into a graph database

Tags: neo4j, arangodb

OpenPhacts is a wonderful source of a number of RDFs related to drug discovery (https://www.openphacts.org/). The data is freely available (https://data.openphacts.org/commercial/2.1/)

Unfortunately there is no example of how to load it into a graph database such as neo4j or arangodb (http://support.openphacts.org/support/solutions/articles/168752-can-i-install-open-phacts-locally-)

Could someone provide a basic example on how to import one of the dozen RDFs into a graph database for a novice graph database user?

Thanks

Iain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post & tool by my colleague

https://jesusbarrasa.wordpress.com/2016/06/07/importing-rdf-data-into-neo4j/

It uses some sensible mapping and provides a Neo4j user defined procedure to do the hard work.

Comment: That is a very informative blog posting explaining the issue I was facing which was to store a triple store in a graph database.